# Can't figure out how to make symfony2.1.5 autoload my vendor library since last update

Tags: php, symfony

I have updated symfony recently and since my vendors are no longer working. I have this error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Paging' not found in /home/username/workspace/project/src/project/projectBundle/Controller/MyController.php on line 22
```

In MyController on lines 22 and 23 i have

```
...
$paging = new \Paging($em, $query, $currentPage, $nbOfResults);
$trainings = $paging->run();
...
```

I tried to add back the library in ../vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php like this as it used to work

```
'Paging' => $baseDir . '/vendor/se/Paging/Paging.php',
```

but i am getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\DebugClassLoader::loadClass(): Failed opening required '/home/username/workspace/project/vendor/se/Paging/Paging.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/username/workspace/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/DebugClassLoader.php on line 82
```

i also tried to add the "appropriate" line in the composer.json file at the root of the project with no success

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/",
        "Paging": "vendor/se/Paging/" //I've added this line
    }
},
```

All this happened after i updated my project using the following commands line

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar update
php composer.phar install
```

And i am also running

```
php composer.phar install
```

everytime i update the composer.json file

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding `"files": ["vendor/se/Paging/Paging.php"]` in your `composer.json` ([Ref](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files))

Comment: I am still having this error : Fatal error: Class 'Paging' not found in /home/username/workspace/project/src/project/projectBundle/Controller/MyController.php on line 22